# For $I_x$ maximal show $I_x = I_y $ or $ I_x \cap I_y = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I_x$ be maximal interval containing x. Show that $I_x = I_y$ or $I_x \cap I_y = \emptyset $

Pf

Assume $I_x$ is maximal, that is $(x - \beta , x + \alpha) \subset A$ is maximal interval.

Suppose $z \in I_x \cap I_y$

WTS $I_x = I_y$ but not sure what Topology makes this true.

Comment: Assume that $I_x$ and $I_y$ are not equal, but intersect non-trivially. What kind of set is then $I_x \cup I_y$?

Comment: since $I_x$ is maximal, thus $I_y$ must equal $I_x$ (contradiction)